# system nullreferenceexception dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
function abc(){

     string Code = (combobox.SelectedItem.Value != null) ? combobox.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

     (save function ....)

}
```

Anyone knows how to I can proceed with save function if the combobox is null value and it pop up error system nullreferenceexception?

Comment: Your functions look like javascript. Are you trying to do something on a client side? Or is it just awful pseudocode?

Comment: Ouch. "Javascript - Just awful pseudo-code ™".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post where you get the `NullReferenceException`, however it's most likely when you are performing this evaluation

```
combobox.SelectedItem.Value != null
```

The ComboBox's `SelectedItem` property will return null if nothing is selected.  If you call the `Value` property on the `null` selected item, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.  What you should be checking is:

```
combobox.SelectedItem != null
```